# how to exit casperJS script when it takes more than 60 seconds?

Tags: casperjs

Sometimes the first inscruction of the casperJS never end:

```
casper.start(url, function() {
   console.log('start', url, email, name);
   // sometimes it never steps here !!

});
```

So the goal would be to exit the script if it takes>30 seconds for isntance.
Any idea ?

I tried with:

```
     waitTimeout: 30000,
     stepTimeout: 30000,

onStepTimeout: function(self) {
        self.exit();
    }
```

But this did not help

Answer (score 0):

There is a sort of hack to exit CasperJS immediately, try it:

```
function exit() {
    var exitTime = new Date();
    console.log('Exiting. Elapsed from start, ms: ' + (exitTime - startTime));

    casper.exit();
    casper.bypass(1);
}

var startTime = new Date();
console.log('Setting exit timeout at ' + startTime);
setTimeout(exit, 30000);   // milliseconds
```